# Под IOS на AS3

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

Сказали, что можно писать под IOS  на AS3. Правда ли это и в какой среде?

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder 4.x (4.5, 4.6, 4.7 - точно), Flash Develop 4.x (4.3, 4.5)

первый платен ~800$ (полнофункциональная среда)
второй бесплатный (чуток меньше по возможностям, но тоже силен, и постоянно апдейтится что важно)

Comment: Сказали на adobe flash cs6 можно ?

Comment: точно точно, можно, совсем забыл

Answer (score 0):

Приложение можно собрать с помощью командной строки используя adt из Flex SDK.
http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f3cb56e2a12cc36970aa-8000.html